# NoSuchMethodError in com.google.api.client library

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-api-client

I'm trying to use the Google Cloud Storage SDK for Java into my Spring application.

Using Maven I've added it to my dependencies:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
   <version>1.31.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I try to initialize the Storage client with:

```
 client = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
                    .setCredentials(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new ClassPathResource("/my/path/to.json").getInputStream()))
                    .build()
                    .getService();
```

but an error occurs

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClient$Builder.setBatchPath
```

I've noticed that in my **google-api-client-1.23.0.jar** libray loaded as dependency no setBatchPath was present.

I've tried to find the issue browsing on web but without fortune.
I cannot understand which library (and version) I need to install in order to make it works.

Answer (score 4):

Eventually I solved, there was a library duplication between my Web Application and Its Business Layer Jar component (I have a multi-module Project).

What I cannot understand is why there was a call to a non-existing method (`AbstractGoogleJsonClient$Builder.setBatchPath`) that was solved in this way.

In  `google-api-client-1.20.0.jar` that method does not exists nor in `google-api-client-1.23.0.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Try reading [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/issues/325), and then you may be able to work around the error.